# How to allow quoted classes inside a php variable?

Tags: php, html

I'm using template pages for literally every page simply because it speeds up the opening of said files for working on them due to slow internet. And because my main page was over 1mil characters and analytics showed slow load times. After the change, it improved significantly. However, I'm unable to use var templates for any of my common snippets because of the quoted classes.

For example, being as I'm using Bootstrap, I'd like to place all the possible Glyphicons in one page so I don't have to type out the entire `<span>` and just the variable.

```
$mail="<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>";
$cart="<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>";
```

How can I allow the quoted classes inside the variable?

Comment: Read the PHP documentation on escaping in strings

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I ask this question here, regardless of how mundane it may be, because I'd rather have an answer come from a person who doesn't speak in textbook language. And being able to ask a question of someone who answers is nice as well. So to be honest, I would've ended up here anyways. I prefer a human approach...

Answer (score 1):

3 Possible options:

1- Either escape them `\`:

```
$mail="<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-envelope\"></span>";
```

2- Use single quotes for the opening and closing quotes, or vice versa.

```
$mail='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>';
```

3- Or:

```
$mail="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></span>";
```

Comment: I tried all 3 and it didn't work so went so far as to take away everything but the class name, no span or quotes, just
`$mail="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope";` 
and stuck into the span element like so:
 `<span class="<?echo $mail?>"></span>`
and even that didn't work. I have no problem using variables elsewhere, any idea?

Comment: @the_software_trader_official, where do you use that variable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I'm trying to use variables for all the icons to avoid typing out the entire span constantly. If you meant where specifically, this particular one is on the subscribe button in the navbar.

Comment: @the_software_trader_official, do you have a public domain? Can you test solution(s) I provided in a isolated environment. Generally, you will end up with Fata error for either no closing the quotes or undefined variable(s).

Comment: I don't know about the "public domain" thing but with my host service, I pretty much have control to edit anything I want. I can make an isolated environment but I didn't see it to be necessary for this situation. I only do that when I make drastic changes that I don't want any random visitors to stumble on in the middle of edits. I'm sorry, I'm just having a hard time understanding your questions lol. When I screw up the code by accident, it does show the stack with whatever errors and I check the error log when I need to. I didn't get any errors this time, just the icon didn't show.

Comment: Can inspect the element in DevTool? Check for `class` attribute, and confirm that glyph icons are loaded. What I went by *public domain* is a link where I can check the problem for myself--I want to see the final output of `$email`

Comment: Oh ok as far as the DevTool, I assume you mean any tool, I use Chrome's tool from time to time but not lately, haven't needed it. I just edit the code and then reload the front-end in another tab. For the classes and icons, yes, everything works fine. I didn't use the provided Bootstrap CSS href because I wanted to edit some things in the styling...by that I mean a bunch of things. Anyways, all the icons work fine when I use the `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-*">` element. What I'm getting at is the site is already built for the most part. Just want to improve the coding. As far as the

Comment: public domain part...I'm guessing your asking is it accessible from outside my pc? Like if it's published on the web? If so, then yes.

Comment: @the_software_trader_official, yes a link to where you published this

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></span>";
$cart="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span>";
```

or

```
$mail='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>';
$cart='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP allows the use of either single or double quotes, so you can simply use single quotes for the string here:

```
$mail='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>';
```

Note that single quotes and double quotes have slightly different behaviors in PHP, and there are also [additional ways to define strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).